# Rails3 ActiveResource Post Call delivers an empty Parameter Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, post, sinatra, parameters, activeresource

I am trying to create a new "Person" in a Sinatra API app from a Rails3 app using ActiveResource and Json.  In Rails3, I created a "Person" model and using ActiveResource I correctly call the API, which correctly reads the URL, but no parameters seem to get passed with the object.

From Rails3 Person Model:

```
class Person < ActiveResource::Base 
  self.site = "http://127.0.0.1:9393/"
  self.collection_name = "person/add"
  self.format = :json 
end
```

From the Rails3 console:

```
u=Person.new({"last_name"=>"Bill", "first_name"=>"Smith"})
=> #<Person:0xb73176f0 @attributes={"last_name"=>"Bill", "first_name"=>"Smith"}, @prefix_options={}> 
puts u.attributes
=> last_nameBillfirst_nameSmith
u.save
=> True
```

From the Sinatra app:

```
puts @app.params.keys
=> Nil
puts @app.params['last_name']
=> Nil
puts @app.params[:last_name]
=> Nil
```

Using the IRB Console this works:

```
Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://127.0.0.1:9393/user/add.json'),{'first_name' => 'Smith', 'last_name' => 'Bill'})
```

Can someone please give some direction as to what I missed or am doing wrong thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Person object should know attributes, as you did on console.  When doing Person.find, it gets attrs via activeresource, but Person.new doesn't know them so that any-way to tell to Person is required at Person.new like the following:

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
   ...
   def new
    @person = Person.new(:name=>nil, :age=>nil, ...)
   end
   ...
```

Does this answer?